# Check if string contains any numbers in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, character, numeric

How do we check if the string contains any numbers?

The best way to check if the string contains all letters is to use `isletter` command but how to go one step further and check if any char in the string is a number?

One way is to convert the string to an array of Chars and cross check if the ascii values belongs to numerics. Is there a simpler way to do this in MATLAB?

Example string: `67 Cliston St`

Comment: A short as `TF = isstrprop(str,'digit')`.

Comment: @marsei I just learned something new!  I think you should post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> exampleString = "67 Cliston St";
>> any(regexp(exampleString ,'[0-9]'))
```

will return true if there is at least one number in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the best way (I'm sure someone else will have a more elegant solution). But this appears to work.

**Approach:**
 1. Split the string up using [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html).
 2. Trim whitespace from the string with [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html).
 3. Use [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html), [`isempty`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html), & [`isnumeric`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html) to check for numbers.

```
str = '67 Cliston St'
newStr = strtrim(split(str))

idxNum = false(length(newStr),1);
for k =1:length(newStr)
    if ~isempty(str2num(newStr{k}))
        idxNum(k) = isnumeric(str2num(newStr{k}))
    end
end
NumPresent = any(idxNum,true);    % returns true if any numerics in the str
```

As I said, it's not pretty.  The other answers are superior. This would fail for `'67Cliston St'` unless you break down the string to each character like

```
newStr = strtrim(split(str,""))
```

which would work fine for `'67Cliston St'`.

---

**Computational Performance:**
Comparing this answer against the other answers:

- `isstrprop(str,'digit')`                ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979040/check-if-string-contains-any-numbers-in-matlab#comment104211448_58979040))
- `any(regexp(exampleString ,'[0-9]'))`   ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979186/8239061))

showed that `isstrprop(str,'digit')` is much faster as the length of the string increases.